# How to use RTK Query's 'upsertQueryData' to add a new entry to the cache?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a GraphQL query setup using the Redux Toolkit's "RTK Query" data fetching functionality. After a mutation related to this query I want to add the returned data from the mutation to be added to the cache without calling the query to the server again. I used the thunk action creator `upsertQueryData` from the API slices utilities for this. ([Reference Documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#upsertquerydata)).

So far I was only able to overwrite the complete cache collection collection related to the Query but did not find a way to just add 1 entry. Perhaps someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

The GraphQL Query, that is working fine. It returns a collection of 'sites'.

```ts
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getSites: builder.query({
        query: () => ({
          document: gql`
            query MyQuery {
              sites {
                id
                name
                description
              }
            }
          `,
        }),
      }),
      ...
```

The mutation with usage of `upsertQueryData`. This overwrites the whole collection of 'sites' of the cache instead of used adding 1 site. To be clear: When sending the mutation I don't have an `id` yet, that is returned by the server through the mutation callback.

```ts
    createSite: builder.mutation({
        query: ({name}) => ({
          document: gql`
          mutation createSite {
            createSite(
              name: "${name}"
              description: "The workspace where Peter works from home in Dordrecht",
              ) {
              site {
                id
                name
                description
              }
            }
          }
        `
        }),
        async onQueryStarted({}, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          const newSiteEntry = data.createSite.site;
          sites.util.upsertQueryData('getSites', { newSiteEntry.id }, newSiteEntry);
        }
```

I expect to that it adds 1 date object to the site cache object instead of overwriting it. So you will get something like this in the cache:

```js
sites: [ 
    {id: '1', name: 'Existing site 1', description: 'description 1'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Existing site 2', description: 'description 2'},
    {id: '3', name: 'New site', description: 'new description'},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You generally have a wrong concept of the cache here. Since your `getSites` endpoint takes no argument and you probably only ever call `useGetSitesQuery()`, there is only ever one cache entry for that (called `getSites(undefined)`), and you want to update that existing cache entry with additional lines.

`upsertQueryData` is for overwriting that whole cache entry with a new value, or in your case, creates completely unrelated cache entries that you will never read from - not what you want to do.

As a result, you want to `updateQueryData` for that one existing cache entry instead:

```js
dispatch(
  api.util.updateQueryData('getSites', undefined, (draft) => {
    draft.sites.push(newSiteEntry)
  })
)
```

Keep in mind though that generally we recommend using `providesTags`/`invalidatesTags` to automatically refetch other endpoints instead of manually doing optimisistic updates on them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your approach doesn't seem to work. The `updateQueryData` callback isn't triggered. If I change, for example, the argument to `{}` instead of `undefined` it is, but the draft is empty. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It depends on how you use `useGetSitesQuery`. If you called `useGetSitesQuery()`, then calling it with `'getSites', undefined` is the way to go. If you call `useGetSitesQuery({})` in your component, then you need to call it with `'getSites', {}`. Both these calls have separate cache entries and you need to know which one to update. And about the draft being empty: Can you please do a `console.log(current(draft))` where `current` is an import from RTK?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip on using the `current` function. With this I could see the actual draft object and notice errors in there caused by a discrepancy related to the return API data and a still active `transformResponse`. This POC project unfortunately did not have type-checking to catch it. Made the necessary changes and your solution indeed works perfectly. This wil give a better user-experience, because of a large data set, compared to re-fetching using tags.